# Cinder volume cant attach or detach

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, cinder, openstack-horizon

After a power failure of the host machine, the openstack cinder volumes have entered a state in which they can not be attached nor detached.

```
~$ nova volume-attach ### ###
ERROR: Invalid volume: already attached (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-###)
~$ nova volume-detach ### ###
ERROR: Invalid volume: already detached (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-###)
```

The status of the volume its self is listed as attached

```
cinder list
+-----+-----------+---------------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|  ID |   Status  |     Display Name    | Size | Volume Type | Bootable | Attached to |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| ### | available |     volume-data     | 690  |   Storage   |  false   |     ###     |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

The volume is not found on the instance even though its listed as attached in the cli and in horizon (the device isnt found in /dev/ nor the mount point in /mnt/)

Comment: Are the cinder volumes in the same machine or in another storage node? Also, did you try creating new volumes and mounting? Volumes are attached with the help of tgt daemon. Try restarting tgt service and also check the files /etc/tgt/targets.conf and /etc/tgt/conf.d/*.conf

Comment: Similar issues. Tgt restart didn't resolve.